# Interesting phenomenon with the $\zeta(3)$ series

Tags: analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I noticed that if one takes certain partial sums of the series for $\zeta(3)$:

$$\zeta(3) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^3}$$

an interesting phenomenon occurs for some values of $N$. For example, with $N = 100000$, the sum is

$$1.2020569031095947853972381615115330296...$$

while the exact value is

$$1.2020569031595942853997381615114499908...$$

.

Note that there are stretches of agreement of the digits beyond the initial segment:

$$1.2020569031(0)9594(7)8539(72)38161511\ (\mathrm{pattern}\ \mathrm{ends})$$

where the parentheses represent disagreeing digits. Why does this happen, what values of "N" give the best "pseudo-approximations", and what is a *proof* of those answers?

Comment: How did you find that sum? Using computer? If so, have you used any big number libraries? Since, regular double precision numbers support only up 15 (or some like that) significant digits. Even then, there might be some round-off errors.

Comment: @Kaster: Yes, by computer, with PARI/GP, which has arbitrary-precision functionality.

Comment: @mikey4ty4 I've never used it, but just curious – how many numbers did you use to store $1/3$ for example? Or I'd say $1/3^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you discovered is very similar to the one exhibited by the [Madhava–Leibniz sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for $\frac{\pi}{4}$:

$$
\frac{\pi}4 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
$$

The decimal expansion of $\pi$ obtained through this formula will contain digits that disagree with $\pi$ at digits predictable by a corresponding sum over Euler numbers. In particular, calculating the first five million digits of the decimal expansion will yield

$$
3.141592\underline{4}5358979323846\underline{4}643383279502\underline{7}841971693993\underline{873}058...
$$

where the underlined digits disagree with the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

The disagreeing digits can be found using

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^\frac{N}{2} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1} \sim \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{E_{2m}}{N^{2m+1}}
$$

In your case, these digits can can be found in a similar way using a sum over Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 8):

I was hoping someone else more knowledgeable would give a more detailed answer, but: the answer is the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) (applied to the difference between the two sums). The points at which the digits don't match correspond to the part of the formula involving a sum over [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers). The values of $N$ which most have this property are powers of $10$.

Comment: So it's the same reason as with the Gregory's series for $\pi/4$ then, right?

Comment: As a probable reference to ['Pi, Euler Numbers, and Asymptotic Expansions'](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P45.pdf) (excellent reading btw...)